# Why don't all SE sites have a standard naming format?

Tags: discussion

Why don't all SE sites have the same naming format? While most of them are `{site-name}.stackexchange.com`, there are others like `serverfault` and `superuser`, and of course `stackoverflow.com` is a unique name in itself.

What were the reasons for these namings?

Comment: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow, Server Fault and Super User (the original trilogy) predate Stack Exchange.